# Are these fibers in my drywall asbestos?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, ceiling-fan, asbestos

While removing/cleaning the bathroom fan hood, I noticed that the edges of the hole in the drywall ceiling have a very fibrous-looking layer/sheet on each side of the gypsum.

This house is very old (going on over 100 years) and I'm not sure when this bathroom's ceiling was last renovated.

I will take a sample to the lab tomorrow, but wondering if anyone has seen the sheeting look so fibrous like this?[image]

[image: Hole around bathroom ceiling fan]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This looks like standard drywall to me.

Comment: I agree older Sheetrock had thicker paper than today's.

Comment: It's standard fiberblass reinforcement. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

If that drywall job is more than 30 years old, it could have asbestos in it, but you wouldn't be able to see it - the fibers are too small.

Those fibers are probably fiberglass - added for strength.

Testing either way, causes no harm.

Answer (score 1):

You won't appreciate this answer, but it is for sure correct:

Nobody online, or in person, can tell you if there's asbestos in that drywall. The photograph does not have high enough resolution to see the fibers.

Indeed, the only way to be **positive** about your question is to send it to a lab for analysis, otherwise you are taking a gamble with both your health, and the legal system.